Rendering many records in a table in Vue with an appropriate scrollbar size
I want to render a table with many records. I've realized that the browser renders the records very slowly in this case.


const { createApp, ref } = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const records = ref([])

    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      records.value.push({ id: i + 1, name: `Record ${i + 1}` })
    }

    return { records }
  }
}).mount('#app')
#app {
  height: 200px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="record in records" :key="record.id">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ record.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



I thought that if I only display what is visible on the screen and hide the rest, it would solve my problem. However, the scrollbar doesn't display properly. It doesn't indicate that I could scroll through the 10.000 records. So, the expected scrollbar size would be as if the table had rendered all 10.000 records. As I scroll, I would then render new rows.


const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue

createApp({
  setup() {
    const records = ref([])
    const visibleRecords = ref([])
    
    const rowHeight = 20 + 1 + 1 /* row height + paddingTop + paddingBottom */
    const scrollableTable = ref(null)
    let tableHeight = 0 /* without header */
    onMounted(() => {
      if (scrollableTable.value) {
        tableHeight = scrollableTable.value.clientHeight - rowHeight /* tableHeight - headerHeight */
      }
    })

    for (let i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
      records.value.push({ id: i + 1, name: `Record ${i + 1}` })
    }
    const updateVisibleRecords = () => {
      if (scrollableTable.value) {
        const start = Math.floor(scrollableTable.value.scrollTop / rowHeight) /* due to scrollTop, we can determine how many records no longer need to be displayed */
        const visibleCount = Math.ceil(tableHeight / rowHeight)
        visibleRecords.value = records.value.slice(start, start + visibleCount)
      }
    }

    onMounted(() => {
      updateVisibleRecords() /* first render */
      scrollableTable.value.addEventListener('scroll', updateVisibleRecords) /* event when scrolled */
    })

    return { visibleRecords, scrollableTable }
  }
}).mount('#app')
#app {
  height: 200px !important;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
table {
  height: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse; /* border: 0px */
}
tr {
  height: 20px  /* row height +20px */
}
th, td {
  padding: 1px; /* row height +1+1px */
}
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table ref="scrollableTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <template v-for="record in visibleRecords" :key="record.id">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ record.id }}</td>
          <td>{{ record.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>



Therefore, the height of the table and the height of one row determine how many records I can display. I need to subtract the height of the header from this. After that, I need to render the rows, and when scrolling, I need to recalculate the currently visible rows: I can determine which will be the first row (how many rows are already hidden) from  scrollTop, and I will add additional displayed rows based on the height.
Question: How can I set the scrollbar size as if I were actually rendering all 10.000 rows? (as seen in the first code snippet, I just don't want to render those rows in the second code snippet, but at the same time, I want the scrollbar)
